# Kofax KScanLib Reference Guide

Tags: kofax

I'm trying to find a developers reference/api reference/sample app or anything along the lines that would help with the Kofax Scan Lib. I've been trying to get hold of Kofax on behalf of a client to resolve a issue to no avail. Google doesn't seem to throw up much use either.

Any and all assistance is greatly appreciated

Thanks,
Brendon

Answer (score 2):

You should find that kind of documentation on the Kofax Capture Installation CD. There are also sample Applications installed with every Kofax Capture installation.

What exactly is your problem?

Comment: exactly it is that Advanced Clarity is loosing pages randomly but I wanted to have a look a a source application to compare the code to an application that I've inherited.